# Android Dialog Button.setonClickListener

Tags: java, android

When I create a dialog and set an onClickListener on a button, the app crashes. The same code works in another Activity, so what's the matter?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    initNewUserDialog();
    initNewLocationDialog();
```

...

```
private void initNewLocationDialog() {
    new_location_Dialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_location);
    new_location_Button = (Button)new_location_Dialog.findViewById(R.id.newlocation_ok);
    //Crash here
    new_location_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new_location_Dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    new_location_editText = (EditText)new_location_Dialog.findViewById(R.id.newlocation_edittext);
    new_location_Dialog.hide();
}
```

Comment: Error is NullPointerException?

Comment: WHy do you have another `setContentView(R.layout.new_location);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to give your dialog a custom layout you should call setContentView() on the dialog itself

```
dialog.setContentView(....);
```

However it's preferred to make your own custom dialog and set your layout in the constructor

```
public class MyDialog extends Dialog {

public MyDialog(Context context) {
    super(context, R.style.your_layout);
}
}
```

check this constructor :

```
Dialog(Context context, int theme)
```

see : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html

Comment: oh yeah i've forgotten dialog.setcontentview... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might check [this](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/) tutorial.

From there I would try with

```
final Dialog new_location_Dialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
    new_location_Dialog.setContentView(R.layout.new_location);
```